# Will the data in fwrite() buffer be flushed when a program exists abnormally?

Tags: c, linux, file, io

`fwrite()` is a library call that firstly buffers the data into a user space buffer, and then calls the `write()` system call later to actually carry out the write operations.

> If a program invokes `fwrite()` to write some data to a file but then exists abnormally, will the buffer of `fwrite()` be <strike>cleared</strike>flushed, or the buffered data will be left over in memory?

The OS I am considering is Linux.

Comment: I guess it may depend on the operating system.

Comment: @MikeCATI have updated the question, and let's say the OS is Linux

Comment: it's probably undefined, because maybe the spec doesn't say. maybe `fflush` is safe to call in the signal handler, maybe not.

Comment: @self Even if it's safe to call in a signal handler, if the signal is due to corruption that crashes the process, anything done after that is suspect. The corruption could have overwritten the output buffer, so you'll write garbage to the file.

Comment: @Barmar I agree. Either way after the program has reached that state, it's better to just crash, use a monitoring system to report it, restart, fix the bug.

Comment: @self *maybe `fflush` is safe to call in the signal handler* - there's no "maybe" about it.  The [answer is "NOT safe".](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Thanks for looking it up, I didn't feel like it.

Comment: By "cleared", do you mean "written to the file", or "erased, so a later process can't accidentally find it"?

Comment: @AndrewHenle You can block other signals from occuring while in a signal handler, you know.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Can you explain a little bit why it is NOT safe to call fflush in the signal hander?

Comment: @PSkocik *You can block other signals from occuring while in a signal handler, you know.*  So?  How would that make `fflush()` async-signal-safe?

Comment: @AndrewHenle `struct sigaction` which you pass to the `sigaction` function has a `sa_mask` field where you specify all the signals that will be blocked during the execution of a signal handler. The current signal is blocked too unless ` !!( sa.sa_flags & SA_NODEFER)`. If you fill it with all signals that the system can throw at you, then you're guaranteed an uninterrupted passage through the signal handler (unless you get a SIGKILL or SIGSTOP or the power goes out or the battery dies or the system crashes).

Comment: @PSkocik So?  Guaranteeing an "uninterrupted passage" does not make a function async-signal-safe.  There's no guarantee that the signal being processed didn't already interrupt an async-signal-safe function.  Calling a non-async-signal-safe function from a signal handler is undefined behavior.  Period.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @QiZhang Why isn't it ever safe to call a non-async-signal-safe function from a signal handler?  Because you never know where the process was when it was interrupted by the signal you're processing.  For example, say it was in `malloc()`.  `malloc()` likely uses a lock or mutex of some kind.  If your signal handler then calls `malloc()` - even indirectly via a function such as `printf()`, your process will deadlock.  Functions can also use static buffers that can be corrupted if that function is called while it's already running.

Comment: @PSkocik  I learned it the hard way - and I don't want to mention how long ago... ;-)

Comment: Data is not "cleared" (set to zero) by a `fwrite()` should it complete or not.  Better to change post to "Will the data in fwrite() buffer be flushed ... "

Comment: Asking if a buffer is "cleared" (set to zero) after `fwrite()` is a separate and valid question especially for security concerns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your program exited abnormally, any buffered data will not be flushed. The OS just says "oh dear me, you left a file descriptor open, I better close that for you" when the process terminates; it has no idea there's some random data lying somewhere in memory that the program intended to write to disk but did not.

Comment: The question is specifically about abnormal termination. The first paragraph of your answer seems superfluous.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, it was just to have a bigger picture. Edited, thank you

Comment: Is it specified in Linux that the data is certainly not flushed?  I would expect on an abnormal exit condition, the buffer _might_ or _might not_ be flushed, possibly even partially flushed.  Certainly the abnormal condition may originate in the middle of writing.

Comment: @chux you are right, to be really precise we don't actually know when the program abnormally exits and so which instructions have been executed. As you know this varies case by case so mine was a "worst case" but highly probable answer ;)

Comment: The OS precautions usually prevents file/memory corruption, but rare partial or random data file write during an abnormal program exit is a _very bad thing_.  My comment was leading  to emphasize that on abnormal exit, abnormal things happen - much specified behavior is not possible.  IMO, code is lucky if it exits gracefully enough not to foul the OS.